# Amazon EC2, Edge locations

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a plan to move my terminal servers to the Amazon cloud. Amazon does not have any trust able zone in Germany and only has some Edge locations which can deliver requested information from the availability zones to the end users with high speed. I was wondering is there any way to use Edge server features for speeding up the terminal servers which are hosted on the trust able  zones in other locations.

Answer (score 2):

Edge locations have nothing to do with EC2. They are used by CloudFront distributions. You can use CloudFront for static web site assets, but nothing like SSH access to EC2 instances.